# Elegant way to code if (10 < x < 20)

Tags: java

Is there an elegant way in Java to code:

```
if (10 < x < 20) {
   ...
}
```

i.e. "if x is between 10 and 20"

rather than having to write

```
if ((x > 10) && (x < 20)) {
   ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if (10 < x && x < 20) { ... }`

Comment: `if (Math.abs(x-15) < 5) {` (I mean, integer overflows don't matter.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  The `<` operator always compares two items and results in a boolean value, so you cannot chain them "elegantly".  You could do this though:

```
if (10 < x && x < 20)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's plenty elegant IMO - there's just not a shorthand/sugar notation for it.

Answer (score 5):

Kenny nailed it in the comments.

```
if (10 < x && x < 20)
```

You want to keep them either both less-than or both greater-than; reversing the direction of the comparison makes for a confusing bit of logic when you're trying to read quickly.

Answer (score 5):

No but you can re-arrange it to make it better, or write a wrapper if it irks you:

```
if (InRange(x, 10, 20)) { ... }
```

Or, as Carl says:

```
if (new Range(10, 20).contains(x)) { ... }
```

Though personally, I don't see the point.  It's a useless abstraction.  The bare boolean statement is perfectly obvious.

Though, now that I think about it, and in light of Carl's comment below, there are times when a Range is a perfectly valid and useful abstraction (e.g. when dealing with Feeds).  So, depending on the semantics of `x`, maybe you do want an abstraction.

Comment: or `new Range(10, 20).contains(x)`.

Comment: @Carl Manaster: Yeah, that would be the hip OO way of doing it.  Good call.

Comment: Yes by all means, let's instantiate a new object rather than subject our beautiful code to an `&&` expression.

Comment: Hip OO will create object to pass as arguments, but not to call a single method on.

Answer (score 4):

```
  if(x < 20)
  {
   if(x > 10)
   {

   //...

   }
  }
```

OR

```
 if(x > 10)
  {
   if(x < 20)
   {

   //...

   }
  }
```

Comment: +1 funny, you sir win one internets, you can pick it up on your way out the door...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is loose the extra parenthesis since the `&&` has a lower precedence than `>` and `<`:

```
if (x > 10 && x < 20) {
   ...
}
```

Other than that: there's no shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

The FASTEST way is a switch.

---

EDIT:

```
switch(x) {
  case 10:
  case 11:
  case 12:
  case 13:
  ...
  case 19: System.out.println("yes");
}
```

is compiled into a jump table, not a long series of ifs.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you meant a bit fuller